# Mysql Order by date multiple columns after joining two tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime

[image]

Now  i want like in 2015-08-04 the middle column of 2015-08-04 should be on same line order and 2015-08-05 should come down of both columns like if the both date matches they  should be in same order like order by both columns its probably like ledger format my sql query

```
SELECT i.* , it.name AS type,td.qty AS issue, td.is_from_stock AS issue_qty_type,v.name AS vendor,o.name AS branch,td.date_from AS issue_date,l.name AS location,td.user AS user,td.remarks AS remarks, os.opening_quantity AS initial_stock,os.remaining_stock AS opening_quantity,os.opening_quantity_unit_price As opening_unit
                         FROM ". $this->tbl_inventories ." AS i 
                        LEFT JOIN ". $this->tbl_inventorytypes ." AS it ON i.type_id = it.id
                        LEFT JOIN ". $this->tbl_distribution ." AS td ON td.item_id = i.item_id AND td.user_branch = i.user_branch
```

And i did like `ORDER BY purchased_date,td.date_from`

Comment: So is this MySQL or SQL Server? Tag appropriately.

Comment: Te order by is lost in your query

Comment: this is mysql i am probably figuring out how to order both in same order if same then should be in same row .

Comment: probably Order by has been able to sort me out with my problems bt dnt knw why its not working in urs

Answer (score 2):

First of all, be bit specific on the image you have provided. I think its not possible to sort the data fetched from MySQL by the date directly as you have tried, since MySQL data output represents a single row for each set of data. 
You have to breakdown to multiple query and put them in the respective arrays, so that you can filter out the data into final array i.e you have to rearange ta data into new array and display it to the table you have snapshot of.